# Deadlock on Generic Waitable Object - Coalesce v IsNull?

Tags: sql, deadlock, sql-server-2016, coalesce, isnull

I am getting a deadlock on a relatively simple query:

```
select coalesce((select max(id) from table where year < 2016),0)
```

Error: 
Transaction was deadlocked on generic waitable object resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Details:

- The table is around 40GB in size, 283M rows
- The table has a clustered column store index.
- The id is a bigint and an identity.
- The table is partitioned on year.
- MaxDOP is set to 4, Cost Threshold to 50.
- 8 logical cores and 32GB RAM, Storage is non-raided SSD.
- Computer is running Windows 8.1 and SQL Server 2016 SP1 Developer
  Edition.

If I use isnull instead of coalesce the error does not occur.

Deadlock Graph:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deadlock>
   <victim-list>
      <victimProcess id="process697ca6c108" />
   </victim-list>
   <process-list>
      <process id="process697ca6c108" taskpriority="0" logused="20000" waittime="2630" schedulerid="4" kpid="648" status="suspended" spid="62" sbid="0" ecid="3" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2017-04-10T09:30:00.030" lastbatchcompleted="2017-04-10T09:30:00.030" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.030" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="MyHost" hostpid="6328" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="90846084" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="390200">
         <executionStack>
            <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="160" sqlhandle="0x0200000000342d3438c95d7d95220ffb20aa484d79bf55d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
         </executionStack>
         <inputbuf>select coalesce( (select max(id) from MyTable where year &amp;lt; 2016),0)</inputbuf>
      </process>
      <process id="process697c9c1088" taskpriority="0" logused="20000" waittime="3923" schedulerid="6" kpid="9016" status="suspended" spid="62" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2017-04-10T09:30:00.030" lastbatchcompleted="2017-04-10T09:30:00.030" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.030" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="MyHost" hostpid="6328" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="90846084" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="390200">
         <executionStack>
            <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="160" sqlhandle="0x0200000000342d3438c95d7d95220ffb20aa484d79bf55d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
         </executionStack>
         <inputbuf>select coalesce( (select max(id) from MyTable where year &amp;lt; 2016),0)</inputbuf>
      </process>
      <process id="process697ca4f848" taskpriority="0" logused="20000" waittime="3923" schedulerid="5" kpid="11792" status="suspended" spid="62" sbid="0" ecid="4" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2017-04-10T09:30:00.030" lastbatchcompleted="2017-04-10T09:30:00.030" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.030" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="MyHost" hostpid="6328" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="90846084" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="390200">
         <executionStack>
            <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="160" sqlhandle="0x0200000000342d3438c95d7d95220ffb20aa484d79bf55d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
         </executionStack>
         <inputbuf>select coalesce( (select max(id) from MyTable where year &amp;lt; 2016),0)</inputbuf>
      </process>
      <process id="process697ca38ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="20000" waittime="3923" schedulerid="2" kpid="16468" status="suspended" spid="62" sbid="0" ecid="1" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2017-04-10T09:30:00.030" lastbatchcompleted="2017-04-10T09:30:00.030" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.030" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="MyHost" hostpid="6328" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="90846084" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="390200">
         <executionStack>
            <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="160" sqlhandle="0x0200000000342d3438c95d7d95220ffb20aa484d79bf55d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
         </executionStack>
         <inputbuf>select coalesce( (select max(id) from MyTable where year &amp;lt; 2016),0)</inputbuf>
      </process>
   </process-list>
   <resource-list>
      <SyncPoint>
         <owner-list>
            <owner id="process697c9c1088" />
            <owner id="process697ca38ca8" />
            <owner id="process697ca4f848" />
         </owner-list>
         <waiter-list>
            <waiter id="process697ca6c108" />
         </waiter-list>
      </SyncPoint>
      <SyncPoint>
         <owner-list>
            <owner id="process697ca6c108" />
         </owner-list>
         <waiter-list>
            <waiter id="process697c9c1088" />
         </waiter-list>
      </SyncPoint>
      <SyncPoint>
         <owner-list>
            <owner id="process697ca6c108" />
         </owner-list>
         <waiter-list>
            <waiter id="process697ca4f848" />
         </waiter-list>
      </SyncPoint>
      <SyncPoint>
         <owner-list>
            <owner id="process697ca6c108" />
         </owner-list>
         <waiter-list>
            <waiter id="process697ca38ca8" />
         </waiter-list>
      </SyncPoint>
   </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: This is a self deadlock and as such, by definition, a bug. Open a support case with Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks.  I've posted this over at MS as well.

Comment: also can you share sample data for us to test and repro the issue

Comment: sadly I can't as it is health data.

Comment: I think Remus is correct, it was the conclusion I was coming to myself.